# Looking for a pager (jQuery plugin)

Tags: jquery

Is there a pager (jQuery plugin) with the following feaures:

< 1 2 3 4 >

- when you click on an arrow the numbers slide to right or left
- when you click on a number you change page
- you have up to 4 numbers (the other pages should be hidden)

thanks

Comment: Have a look at this jquery pagination plugin: - http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery Pagination Plugin](http://blog.ajaxmasters.com/jquery-pagination-plugin/) for this, and [can see a demo here](http://tutorials.ajaxmasters.com/pagination-demo/).

Change the options in the demo to get the results you describe:

- Number of pagination links shown: **4**
- Number of start and end points: **0**

Comment: mhm.. thanks. Do you know how I could apply it to an existent list of items ? Let's say I already have the html code with a working static pager <ul> <li> <li> ... </ul>. I just want to add the sliding effect.